# how do i get values from dynamically created textboxes?

Tags: javascript, textbox

I am createting textboxes dynamically at runtime on click of a button. The number of textboxes generated is not fixed. How do i get the values from the dynamically created textboxes and store them to the variable. Below is my code.

```
function AddTextBox() {
var div = document.createElement('DIV');
div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");

document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
"<div>" + "</div>";
}
```

Comment: When you are creating the TextBoxes, you can add an ID to it which will help you access that later.

Comment: The above is JavaScript and you have tagged this as C#. I presume you are creating the textboxes serve side? Can you include the C# code?

Answer (score 1):

you can get etch textbox value using textbox Id if you have serialized id.

```
   $('#button').click(function () {
      $.each($('[id^=txt]'), function (i, item) {
        var grade = $(this).val();
        alert(grade);
      });
    });
```

Or you can get all the input type text box value using this.

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(i, item) {
     var grade =  $(item).val();
     alert(grade);
 });
```